# Error en visual studio code con php

Tags: php, visual-studio

Hasta ayer programaba en php con unas extensiones desde visual studio code, pero hoy al volver a abrirlo no me reconocía ningún fichero php. He estado leyendo que tenía que añadir un path etc etc... pero nada de esto funciona.

Uso xampp y tengo la version de php 7.2.1. Añadi el path y todo pero nada.

Adjunto capturas

[php error in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gBuZ.png)

[no php to configure in vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci6wp.png)

[my C:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wqVO.png)

[PATH configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKlel.png)

Comment: POR qué el path tendría que ser del php que está dentro de xampp

Comment: Ya le tengo puesto, no vale el que puse?

Comment: si tienes la instalación regular el path debería ser C:\xampp\php

Comment: si, pero añado eso y nada, sigue igual... ¿Que extension deberia añadir a vsc para configurar?

Comment: prueba así php.validate.executablePath="C:/xampp/php/php.exe"

Comment: Creo que deberías probar con invertir "C:\php7\php.exe" por "C:/php7/php.exe".

Comment: error al menos dentro de Windows la ruta si es con \